# Duda con actualizar campo en Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy intentando cambiar el valor de un campo del atributo prem pero sin éxito. El campo prem es un ENUM de si o no, y tengo esto:

Comment: ¿Nos añades el resultado de SELECT DISTINCT premium FROM oficinas; para ver qué datos de tipo ENUM has almacenado en ese campo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás intentando aplicar dos criterios simultáneamente, deberías añadir un AND, o lo que proceda, tras el primer WHERE; así como el código de la oficina, tanto después de ese operador AND, como en los campos que proyectas en el GROUP BY. Utilizando JOIN y HAVING la consulta resultará más rápida y más corta.

```
UPDATE oficinas JOIN (
    SELECT codigooficina
      FROM oficinas JOIN empleados USING(codigooficina)
      JOIN clientes ON empleados.codigoempleado = codigoempleadorepventas
      JOIN pedidos USING(codigocliente)
      JOIN detallepedidos USING(codigopedido)
      GROUP BY 1 HAVING SUM(cantidad * preciounidad) > 15000  
    ) c1 USING(codigooficina)
  SET premium = 'NO';
```

Comment: Ya esta el codigo en la pregunta

Comment: me cambia todas las filas, no solo las que se cumplen en la condicion de la suma > importe